# Custom view criteria in oracle adf

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I had created one search page using custom viewcriteria with five parameters.In my search page working perfect.I have one doubt,we are entering the some parameters in the search page to get the details from one table, Here i need that values which we are entered in that boxes for using that values into a one java class.

How get those values?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ,This link can help you.you should glance

http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/07/implementing-custom-search-form-in-adf.html

Answer (score 0):

You can read the search value from a custom BC method (either on AM or VO impl level):

> ViewCriteriaImpl applyVC =
>   (ViewCriteriaImpl)myViewObject.getViewCriteria("MyViewCriteriaName")
>   while(applyVC.hasNext) {    Row vcrow = applyVC.next();    .... }